# how to redirect the base URL if not found the correct path in CodeIgniter3

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, redirect, codeigniter-3

I want to redirect the faulty links to the home page. Usually all the faulty links or links without correct path shows the 404 page but I want to redirect these kind of URLs to home page.

in routes

$route['404'] = 'home/error404';
$route['404_override'] = 'home/error404';

.htaccess

ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.safehousepg.in/404

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in your .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.safehousepg.in/404/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <YourRelativePathToPHPFile>/404.php [L]
```

404.php in the last line will be your rout for redirect.